# How to dynamically enable a payment method

Tags: rules, commerce

I have a product display node with a field "Choose one or more payment method" - Field type: List(text)-  for choosing  the payment method.
I sell only one product at a time.
Is it possible to dynamically enable a payment method according to the value set in the field of the product display node? I would like to do this with rules module.

Comment: do you mean the rules? if so the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes, sorry! With rules. How can I do?

Comment: When you add a payment method you can add a condition, you should try adding a condition based on the field on the product.

Comment: The field is in product display and I can't retrieve it in the condition. I've try to add a loop through line item but it doesn't works.

Comment: Could you add the field to the product instead of the product display?

Comment: Is not the best way for me but I can do this. Anyway the conditions in add payment method refer to order and not to product and so I can't retrieve the field also in this case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12054/discussion-between-daniel-harper-and-derio)